# Create DB by taking DBName from C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, hard-coding

I've a requirement to create DB by taking the DB name from the C# application. Basically, avoiding hard-coding of DBname in the sql script. ex: "create Database abc". In this "abc" must be passed as parameter.

Once i read the DBName from the application, can anyone please suggest how to pass DBName to the script file?  The Script file will be read by the C# application again and executes it.

-Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. Use a dynamic statement, and use it to create the database:

   ```
   SET @sqlText = 'create database ? ...';
   PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlText;
   EXECUTE stmt using @name;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
   ```

   Pass in the name as parameter.
2. Create the statement in .NET:

   ```
   string statement = string.Format("create database {0} ...", databaseName);
   ```

Comment: @user3744269: Was this post helpful to you?